# How to instantiate a structural type in Scala?

Tags: scala, duck-typing, structural-typing

I'm trying to create a structural type in Scala to avoid defining intermediate classes. Essentially, I just want to define a structure that will be marshalled/unmarshalled to/from a JSON string.

For example, to describe the following JSON

```
{
    "query": {
        "range" : {
            "number" : {
                "gte": 123, 
                "lte": 456
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a corresponding structural type:

```scala
  //structural
  type NumberRange = {val range: {val number: {val gte: Long; val lte: Long}}}

  //named
  case class NumberRangeQuery(query: NumberRange)

  //instance
  val nrq: NumberRangeQuery = ???
```

What would be the correct way to create an instance of `NumberRangeQuery`?

Comment: if you knew the answer at the very point you asked the question why did you asked the question? because you answered with in a minute.

Comment: @RamanMishra Sadly, stackoverflow encourages people to ask questions and then answer them themselves. See [this help topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @Tim I am not saying that don’t answer your own questions but if you answer with in one minute it seems op already knew the answer

Comment: @RamanMishra Yes, but that is OK according to the help topic: "If you have a question that you already know the answer to [...] it's perfectly okay to ask and answer your own question on a Stack Exchange site."

Comment: @Tim, why "Sadly"? I got the answer before I got a chance to post the question. Since the answer did not come from StackOverflow, I posted my answer with my question, so that others may benefit from the information. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sadly this wastes other people's time trying to answer questions when the OP already knows the answer, and because it is often used as a way of showing off or advertising.

Comment: @Tim That's unfortunate. When an answer is posted with the question and not separately, I would expect it to be clear and not confuse people.

Comment: @Dmitry The answer was posted after the question, so there was a period when your question was there but not your answer. But the real problem is that this is a contrived question about a situation that should never happen.

Comment: @Tim the delay in the answer post is something you may (and maybe should) take with StackOverflow maintainers. It is indeed annoying that an accompanying answer appears with a delay. Regarding the question problem - there's a way to express your criticism by voting down.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in this case is not to use structural types but rather spend the effort to use case classes and make the code much more readable and efficient:

```
case class Number(gte: Long, lte: Long)
case class Range(number: Number)
case class Query(range: Range)
case class NumberRangeQuery(query: Query)

val nrq: NumberRangeQuery = NumberRangeQuery(
  Query(
    Range(
      Number(1, 3)
    )
  )
)
```

Why would you choose structural types over concrete types in this case?

Comment: This is obviously a cleaner solution, but the question is "how" to instantiate a structural type, rather than whether it's the right thing to do :)

Comment: @Dmitry This is a classic [XY question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) where you are trying to fix your chosen solution rather than fixing the actual problem.

Comment: perhaps the question is not clear and I should edit it. The reason I wanted to use a structural type is to *avoid* "polluting" the namespace with classes for the intermediate (nested) values.

Comment: Structural types are not the answer to the problem of namespace pollution. You can avoid polluting the namespace by simply putting the code inside `{}` so the symbols don't escape, or putting them in a `object` so that they need to be qualified.

Comment: Can you please add a demonstration of the anonymous class initialization to your answer? It'll then be complete and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score -2):

To create an in-line instance of a class implementing the structural type you can use the following method:

```scala
//instance
  val nrq: NumberRangeQuery = NumberRangeQuery(new {
    val range = new {
      val number = new {
        val gte = 1: Long 
        val lte = 3: Long
      }
    }
  })
```

Note that instantiating "anonymous" structural types comes with at least 2 penalties:

1) It's arguably readable code
2) Scala will use reflection in runtime to dispatch methods on such instances ([discussion here](https://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/6834))

Comment: This is not instantiating the structural type. This is creating a class which implements the structural type and instantiating that class.

Comment: Thanks @JörgWMittag. Updated.